# how to create a wsdl to accept any type of wsdl content from the consumer

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I have a challenge, we are doing poc now, and we have got a weird request to log the different types of web service requests coming from the consumer into our application.
how do i create a generic wsdl to accept any type of content from the consumer? I know this may sounds stupid, we have got this requirement, need some inputs on this